# How to filter out nulls in google bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I don't seem to find a way in Bigquery to filter out `nulls` like we do in SQL server database, e.g. `WHERE Column1 IS NOT NULL`.

Can anyone shed some light on this please?

Thanks.

Comment: The syntax you describe should work - can you share your code so we can identify any issues, along with some sample results where you are seeing null values?

Comment: When you are selecting from a table and providing filter like 'where column1 is not null' then it works in BQ. I am not sure if your question explains the proper scenario for which you want help. Please share your input, desired output and basic code to understand better.

Comment: Thanks. I think I made a mistake. Yes, it works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The syntax you provide should work fine, the ***where*** operator filters the rows in your dataset before executing the select. The syntax is as follows:

```
Select *
from table_source
where column is not NULL;
```

If you want to read more about the ***where*** operator, please refer to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#where-clause).

In addition if you want to replace the null values, you can use the [IFNULL()](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/IFNULL-Function_66194064) function. The syntax would be:

```
Select *, 
       IFNULL(column, 'string_to_replace_null_value') as new_column
from table_source;
```

I hope it helps.